# Can future tense be used with “this week”?

Tags: grammar, tense

I saw an answer to an exercise on EnglishPage:
The students are usually taught by Mrs. Monty. However, this week they **are being** taught by Mr. Tanzer.

Can we use “will be” here?

I think with “will be”, it means the teaching will take place in this week but not currently. Is is right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct.

> They ***will be taught*** this week.

Here, the future tense implies that the teaching has not occurred yet. ***This week*** specifies that the teaching will happen this week. Therefore, we can infer that the class or classes have not yet occurred but will occur later this week.

> They ***are being taught*** this week.

This is the present continuous form of "to be taught." The lessons are currently being taught, which can also mean that some of the lessons may occur later in the week -- assuming there is more than one class per week.